# InvalidArgument exception on remove of item

Tags: c#

I have a listBox1 in which items are collected.

A timer1 that start with a button1 click.

And a progressBar1

Here is the complete code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Interval = 500;
    progressBar1.Maximum = listBox1.Items.Count;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x.Send("<iq type='set' to='" + textBox6.Text + "@conference.jabber.com'>" + 
           "<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>" +
           "<item jid='" + listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + 
           "@nimbuzz.com' affiliation='member'/></query></iq>");
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    progressBar1.Value += 1;
    groupBox4.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
}
```

The code above runs well but when 0 item is left in listBox1 the progressBar1 Stops There comes and error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled Message: *InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index*

Comment: Yes, if you read [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see that RemoveAt throws an exception when index is equal to or greater than Count. Because there's nothing to remove. If you have no items, you can't remove one. What's your question, exactly? I guess it's not "how can I remove an item when I have none".

Comment: What is your purpose on using `timer`?

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple check

```
if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.Items.Count > 0) {
 x.Send("<iq type='set' to='" + textBox6.Text + "@conference.jabber.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item jid='" + listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + "@nimbuzz.com' affiliation='member'/></query></iq>");
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
        groupBox4.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Value of '79' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ParamName=Value
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)

Comment: Now it a different story. Your progress bar has a maximum limit on its value.

Comment: progressBar1 is full when the listBox1 is empty

Comment: I think you have a logical/runtime error in your sample code for `ProgressBar` control, you remove item in `listbox` and then you increment the value of `ProgressBar` after initializing the the value of `PregressBar` equal to `listbox` item count.

Comment: What is your purpose on using timer?

Comment: timer changes the affiliation of items in groupchat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54830/discussion-between-dr-zeus-and-jade).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is essentially the same as what has already been posted, but with some improved formatting. It is good to use `string.Format()` to help improve the readability of your code.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        x.Send(string.Format(
            "<iq type='set' to='{0}@conference.jabber.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'><item jid='{1}@nimbuzz.com' affiliation='member'/></query></iq>",
            textBox6.Text,
            listBox1.Items[0].ToString()));

        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
        groupBox4.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```